# Man having 1 light year height can see his whole body?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light

Here is my one imagination and few questions on it:

One man standing in universe at somewhere. His height is 1 light year.

Can he see his whole body with exact age of his eyes?

What he can see if he turns down eyes to see his legs and see his organs one by one from legs to chest?

If he moves hands from bottom to top, will hands movement be visible by him?

Consider man's latest age is 20 years.

Comment: Why put it in the context of a human body? It's the same type question how long does it take for a radio signal to go from Earth to the New Dawn probe and the response from the probe to return to Earth. The body context makes no difference other than signals from the brain to muscles travel slower than c.

Comment: You can't see your "whole body with exact age" of your eyes either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He cannot see his whole body at the same 'age' his eyes are if you are asking for what an instantaneous age across his body is. He would see the age of other parts of his body as younger because it takes time for light to travel from his body to his eyes. He would see his feet at somewhere around 19 years old and the rest of his body some version of: `20-(distance away in lightyears)` *assuming he was all created at the same time* (which you seem to assume).

However, this is not the best question because there is no instantaneous 'same time' in the universe. To put it simply, general relativity says everything is relative.

If he chooses to move his hands from bottom to top, it will take time for the signal from his brain to travel to his muscles in his arms. His hands cannot move as we normally would because they are limited by the speed of light, and it would take time for him to see his hands move as per the above.